# mysqldump fails to dump database

Tags: php, mysql

I m taking backup of my mysql database using php code. I used following code

```
$username =escapeshellcmd($db_user);
$password =escapeshellcmd($db_pass);
$hostname =escapeshellcmd($db_host);
$database =escapeshellcmd($db_name);

$backupFile='/dbBackup/'.date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").'.sql.gz';
$command = "mysqldump -u$username -p$password -h$hostname $database | gzip > $backupFile";

system($command, $result);
```

I put this code in php file and call this file for generating backup in dbBackup folder. I have two servers on one server this code works perfectly but on second server this code generates .sql zip file which contains only some part of sql as follows

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.23, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: zm3_quizzes
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.23-55

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the MySQL versions on both servers? There's a bug documented [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34192) which might be related... your version should have it fixed, but make sure you check both servers have the same version, just in case.

Comment: thanks for reply. I checked versions on both servers they are same.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem.  As it turned out, the user for the database that failed did not have "Lock Tables" privileges.  I changed the privileges for the user (in my case, using cPanel) and my script worked.